# SwiftUI - picker view after timer expires not working as expected-seems to have a pulsating effect

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm building a very simple timer app, and what I want it to do is that I want to show a picker view once the timer expires to add more time and go back to the timer. However, although it compiles, it gives me a really weird functionality shown below.

[image: Error Recording]

I do believe the `secondView` struct is the culprit here, but I'm not sure the exact problem. The code is attached below:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var secondScreenShown = false
    @State var timerVal = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Picker(selection: $timerVal, label: Text("Set Half Time")) {
                Text("1").tag(60)
                Text("2").tag(120)
                Text("20").tag(1200)
                Text("25").tag(1500)
                Text("30").tag(1800)
                Text("35").tag(2100)
                Text("40").tag(2400)
                Text("45").tag(2700)
                
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(secondScreenShown: $secondScreenShown, timerVal: timerVal), isActive: $secondScreenShown) {
                Text("Set Half!")
            }
        }
    }
}
struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var secondScreenShown: Bool
    @State var timerVal: Int
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack{
                if timerVal > 0 {
                    Text("Time Remaining in Half")
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                    HStack(spacing: 33){
                        Text("\(timerVal / 60)")
                            .font(.system(size: 40))
                        Text("\(timerVal % 60)")
                            .font(.system(size: 40))
                            .onAppear(){
                                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
                                    if self.timerVal > 0 {
                                        self.timerVal -= 1
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        
                    }
                    HStack{
                        Text("Minutes")
                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                        Text("seconds")
                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        self.secondScreenShown = false
                    }) {
                        Text("Cancel")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
    
                } else {
                    // This is the code I believe has the error
                    VStack{
                        Picker(selection: $timerVal, label: Text("Add Stoppage Time?")) {
                            Text("1").tag(60)
                            Text("2").tag(120)
                            Text("3").tag(180)
                            Text("4").tag(240)
                            Text("5").tag(300)
                            Text("6").tag(360)
                            Text("7").tag(420)
                            Text("8").tag(480)
                            Text("9").tag(540)
                        }
                        NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(secondScreenShown: $secondScreenShown, timerVal: timerVal), isActive: $secondScreenShown) {
                            Text("Add Stoppage")
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                        }
                        Button(action: {
                            self.secondScreenShown = false
                        }) {
                            Text("Done")
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
            }

            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Does this compile? A `@State` variable must be initialized. And the timer never stops.

Comment: It does compile. I can edit the code to include the full code.

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) there are a few very basic errors in your code. `@State` is a source of truth. It will have no relation with an `@State` as a parent beyond the initial value. `@Binding` is a two-way connection. If you really think about those concepts you will see why your code isn't working.

Comment: Take a look at https://medium.com/@pwilko/how-not-to-create-stopwatch-in-swift-e0b7ff98880f for some tips on creating a model for elapsed time, why using a counter is a bad idea and a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using `secondScreenShown` to show the third screen as well.  Since that value is `true`, it automatically takes the link and you continuously push additional screens.

You don't really need to push another screen.  It is enough if the **Add Stoppage** just updates the time, but the picker needs to use a new variable so that it doesn't update `timerVal` until the button is pressed.

I added another state var called `@State var overtime: Bool`.  This is used to avoid repeatedly showing the **Add Stoppage** every time the timer reaches zero.

Also, you should `.invalidate()` the `Timer` when it reaches 0 so that it can be freed and you don't end up with multiple timers running.

Here is the updated code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var secondScreenShown = false
    @State var timerVal = 60
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Picker(selection: $timerVal, label: Text("Set Half Time")) {
                Text("1").tag(60)
                Text("2").tag(120)
                Text("20").tag(1200)
                Text("25").tag(1500)
                Text("30").tag(1800)
                Text("35").tag(2100)
                Text("40").tag(2400)
                Text("45").tag(2700)
                
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(secondScreenShown: $secondScreenShown, timerVal: timerVal), isActive: $secondScreenShown) {
                Text("Set Half!")
            }
        }
    }
}
struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var secondScreenShown: Bool
    @State var timerVal: Int
    @State var stoppage: Int = 60
    @State var overtime: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack{
                if timerVal > 0 || overtime {
                    Text("Time Remaining in Half")
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                    HStack(spacing: 33){
                        Text("\(timerVal / 60)")
                            .font(.system(size: 40))
                        Text("\(timerVal % 60)")
                            .font(.system(size: 40))
                            .onAppear(){
                                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { tim in
                                    if self.timerVal > 0 {
                                        self.timerVal -= 1
                                        if self.timerVal == 0 {
                                            tim.invalidate()
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        
                    }
                    HStack{
                        Text("Minutes")
                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                        Text("seconds")
                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        self.secondScreenShown = false
                    }) {
                        Text("Cancel")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
    
                } else {
                    // This is the code I believe has the error
                    VStack{
                        Picker(selection: $stoppage, label: Text("Add Stoppage Time?")) {
                            Text("1").tag(60)
                            Text("2").tag(120)
                            Text("3").tag(180)
                            Text("4").tag(240)
                            Text("5").tag(300)
                            Text("6").tag(360)
                            Text("7").tag(420)
                            Text("8").tag(480)
                            Text("9").tag(540)
                        }
                        Button(action: {
                            self.timerVal = self.stoppage
                            self.overtime = true
                        }) {
                            Text("Add Stoppage")
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                        }
                        Button(action: {
                            self.secondScreenShown = false
                        }) {
                            Text("Done")
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
            }

            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```